# how to crop a polynomial shape from an image

Tags: javascript, drawing

I searched for this question on the internet and the methods I found were about cropping images with `CSS` or cropping a rectangular shape with `JavaScript`. What I want is to crop a polynomial with `JavaScript`.

I have an Array of cartesian points `Arr=[{x:x1,y:y1},{x:x2,y:y2},{x:x3,y:y3}]` that makes a polynomial. The first element in the array equals the last element in the array.

Using the function `crop`, I want to use this array to crop a polynomial from a picture `imageObj` and save it in `imageObj2`.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
var imageObj2 = new Image();
var arr=[];
arr.push({x:x1,y:y1});
arr.push({x:x2,y:y2});
arr.push({x:x3,y:y3});
imageObj.src = 'link of imageObj';
crop(arr[],imageObj);
```

How can I build this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a canvas for this. It's the only way to modify an image permanently. This will also require CORS to be fulfilled.

As image loading is asynchronous that will be an aspect that needs to be dealt with either using Promises (not supported in IE) or callbacks. For the example below I'll use callbacks.

First part is the loading process as well as handling the callbacks properly.

The second part (`cropImage()`) show the complete process of cropping the image and ending up with a new image of the size of the crop.

It assumes the points to be scaled relative to original image size (tip: you don't need a closing point, ie. end point = first point, as `fill()` will automatically close the path for you).

```js
var srcImage = new Image();           // create image object
srcImage.onload = crop;               // set callback
srcImage.crossOrigin = "";            // for demo: =anonymous crossOrigin usage
srcImage.src = "http://i.imgur.com/U9X0n84.jpg";

document.body.appendChild(srcImage);  // add original to DOM for comparsion

function crop() {
  // - image is loaded and is represented as "this" inside this callback
  
  // some "random" points for demo
  var arr = [{x: 10, y: 90}, {x: 70, y: 10}, {x: 400, y: 200}, {x: 200, y: 220}];
  
  // do the cropping, provide callback
  cropImage(this, arr, function(img) {
      // img is the cropped image - add to DOM for demo
      document.body.appendChild(img);
  })
}

function cropImage(image, arr, callback) {
  
  // create a canvas element, and get 2D context for it:
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      i, minx = 10000, miny = 10000, maxx = -1, maxy = -1;
  
  // find min max of array points here:
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].x < minx) minx = arr[i].x;
    if (arr[i].x > maxx) maxx = arr[i].x;
    if (arr[i].y < miny) miny = arr[i].y;
    if (arr[i].y > maxy) maxy = arr[i].y;
  }
  
  // set proper size:
  canvas.width = maxx - minx;
  canvas.height = maxy - miny;
  
  // translate context so corner of clip is (0,0)
  ctx.translate(-minx, -miny);
  
  // draw in image;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  
  // create a clip path:
  ctx.moveTo(arr[0].x, arr[0].y);
  for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) ctx.lineTo(arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
  
  // set comp. mode so image within path is kept:
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
  ctx.fill();
  
  // done, create an image object:
  var dstImage = new Image();
  dstImage.onload = function() {callback(this)};
  dstImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();     // saves PNG in this case as data-uri
}
```